# Can someone help me update my Apex Class so that it doesn't create or get an opportunityID if a box in the screen flow is checked?

Tags: apex

I have a apex class that autoconverts leads based on the inputs I am supplying it with. If the opportunityId is not input, an opportunity is created.
I don't always want an opportunity to be created upon conversion, only if the user selects to create a new one in a screen flow.

Can anyone help me achieve this please?

```
public class Lead_Conversion_CLONE {

    @InvocableMethod(label = 'CLONE Auto Convert Leads')
    public static List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> LeadAssign(List<LeadConversionRequest> leadConversionRequests) {
        List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> leadConvertResults = new List<LeadConvertResultWrapper>();

        try {
            List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

            for (LeadConversionRequest request : leadConversionRequests) {
                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(request.LeadId);
                Leadconvert.setAccountId(request.AccountId);
                Leadconvert.setContactId(request.ContactId);
                Leadconvert.setOpportunityId(request.OpportunityId);
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus('Recycled');
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
            }

            if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
                Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert, false);

                // Process the results and add to the output variable
                for (Database.LeadConvertResult result : lcr) {
                    LeadConvertResultWrapper wrapper = new LeadConvertResultWrapper();
                    wrapper.isSuccess = result.isSuccess();
                    wrapper.leadId = result.getLeadId();
                    wrapper.contactId = result.getContactId();
                    wrapper.opportunityId = result.getOpportunityId();
                    wrapper.accountId = result.getAccountId();
                    leadConvertResults.add(wrapper);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log or handle the exception as needed
            System.debug('Exception during lead conversion: ' + e.getMessage());

            // Set the error message in the wrapper
            LeadConvertResultWrapper errorWrapper = new LeadConvertResultWrapper();
            errorWrapper.errorMsg = 'Exception during lead conversion: ' + e.getMessage();
            leadConvertResults.add(errorWrapper);
        }

        return leadConvertResults;
    }

    public class LeadConversionRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'LeadId' required = true)
        public Id LeadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'AccountId' required = false)
        public Id AccountId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'ContactId' required = false)
        public Id ContactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'OpportunityId' required = false)
        public Id OpportunityId;
    }

    public class LeadConvertResultWrapper {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Is Success')
        public Boolean isSuccess;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Lead ID')
        public Id leadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Contact ID')
        public Id contactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Opportunity ID')
        public Id opportunityId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Account ID')
        public Id accountId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Error Message')
        public String errorMsg; // New field to capture error messages
    }
}
```

Thanks to @sfdcfox the issue is now resolved! Here is the full working class:

````
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'CLONE Auto Convert Leads')
    public static List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> LeadAssign(List<LeadConversionRequest> leadConversionRequests) {
        List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> leadConvertResults = new List<LeadConvertResultWrapper>();

        try {
            List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

            for (LeadConversionRequest request : leadConversionRequests) {
                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(request.LeadId);
                Leadconvert.setAccountId(request.AccountId);
                Leadconvert.setContactId(request.ContactId);
                Leadconvert.setOpportunityId(request.OpportunityId);
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus('Recycled');
                LeadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(request.DoNotCreateOpportunity == true);
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
            }

            if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
                Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert, false);

                // Process the results and add to the output variable
                for (Database.LeadConvertResult result : lcr) {
                    LeadConvertResultWrapper wrapper = new LeadConvertResultWrapper();
                    wrapper.isSuccess = result.isSuccess();
                    wrapper.leadId = result.getLeadId();
                    wrapper.contactId = result.getContactId();
                    wrapper.opportunityId = result.getOpportunityId();
                    wrapper.accountId = result.getAccountId();
                    leadConvertResults.add(wrapper);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log or handle the exception as needed
            System.debug('Exception during lead conversion: ' + e.getMessage());

            // Set the error message in the wrapper
            LeadConvertResultWrapper errorWrapper = new LeadConvertResultWrapper();
            errorWrapper.errorMsg = 'Exception during lead conversion: ' + e.getMessage();
            leadConvertResults.add(errorWrapper);
        }

        return leadConvertResults;
    }

    public class LeadConversionRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'LeadId' required = true)
        public Id LeadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'AccountId' required = false)
        public Id AccountId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'ContactId' required = false)
        public Id ContactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'OpportunityId' required = false)
        public Id OpportunityId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'DoNotCreateOpportunity' required = false)
        public Boolean DoNotCreateOpportunity;
    }

    public class LeadConvertResultWrapper {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Is Success')
        public Boolean isSuccess;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Lead ID')
        public Id leadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Contact ID')
        public Id contactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Opportunity ID')
        public Id opportunityId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Account ID')
        public Id accountId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Error Message')
        public String errorMsg; // New field to capture error messages
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new property to the LeadConversionRequest class:

```
@InvocableVariable(label = 'DoNotCreateOpportunity' required = false)
public Boolean DoNotCreateOpportunity;
```

And then set the flag for that in your invocable method:

```
LeadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(request.DoNotCreateOpportunity == true);
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you so much.